# Count google results with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

So im trying to get Google count results through java **without Api**. i tried to do it with the Jsoup library. the problem is he cant find the div im looking for called resultStats.

my code:

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc  = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1LENP_enIL60,jvagazvgsaswgfwf7IL607&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q="+query).get();
Elements info = doc.select("div#resultStats");
```

[image: this is the div I'm looking for, inspect element on Google search...]

Comment: Works here: http://try.jsoup.org/~bcToNSN24AqmTBfS8sVnFqKo2_w  maybe view content of `doc` to see if it actually contains the page and what you are looking for ? `doc.text()`

Comment: i think it is but it give me only the elements at the top for some reason...pls help me!

Comment: Print `doc` and see if it contains `div` with id `resultStats`. If it is not then either you need to include proper user-agent or this div is generated by JavaScript (in that case Jsoup will not be able to help you since because it is only nice HTML/XML parser, not browser emulator, use Selenium maybe).

Comment: var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://www.google.com/search?q=love");
var div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='resultStats']");
var text = div.InnerText;   thats for me on c# how i do it at java?

Comment: That is JavaScript code, not Java. Like I said you don't need XML/HTML parser, but browser emulator like Selenium web driver.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something like:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.co.il/search?q=test").get();
String info = doc.select("div#resultStats").text();
System.out.println(info);
```

---

The problem was with your **google query url** and not the `jsoup` code itself.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark ✔ in the middle of the vote arrows, tks !